# Регулярные выражения: из массива строк исключить подстроку

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, visual-studio

Возникла необходимость в большом куске кода внести массовую замену. Использую штатный инструмент Visual Studio 2017 и регулярные выражения для поиска. Подразумеваю, что синтаксис выражений в строке поиска соответствует синтаксису регулярных выражений в C#.
Есть следующая строка

> get_Label().get_UserLocalizedLabel().get_Label();

В поиске задаю выражение `get_(\w*)\(\)`

Получаю результат поиска:

> `get_Label()`.`get_UserLocalizedLabel()`.`get_Label()`;

А нужен вот такой результат:

> `get_`Label`()`.`get_`UserLocalizedLabel`()`.`get_`Label`()`;

То есть необходимо исключить слово между `get_` и `()`. Пробовал `get_(?!\w*)\(\)`, но не преуспел.

Comment: А в итоге что должно получиться? Нужно заменить `_get_` и `()` на что-то (например, чтобы получилось `GetLabel.GetUserLocalizedLabel`, или вовсе их удалить, или что-то другое?

Comment: О, переделка кода с джавы...

Comment: @Qwertiy ага, мне это тоже доставило :). Только это не джава, это декомпиляция решарпера так проперти обработала :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно заменить `get_` и `()` на что-то, то подойдёт такой вариант:

Find what:

```
get_(\w*)\(\)
```

Replace with:

```
Get$1
```

Для

> get_Label().get_UserLocalizedLabel().get_Label()

результат:

> GetLabel.GetUserLocalizedLabel.GetLabel

Comment: Конечный результат должен был быть `GetLabel.GetUserLocalized.Label` Буду благодарен, если поясните, как работает $1. В своем примере я показывал, что выделяет при поиске Студия. Думал сделать нужную выборку и заменить на пустую строку. Но $1 все упростило.

Comment: @Dismantled `$1` - это первая найденная группа. Группа - это часть рег. выражения, взятая в скобки. В данном случае - `\w*`. Если строка всегда именно `get_Label().get_UserLocalizedLabel().get_Label()`, то получить `GetLabel.GetUserLocalized.Label` можно с помощью замены `get_(\w*)\(\)\.get_(\w*)\(\)\.get_(\w*)\(\)` на `Get$1.Get$2.$3`. Не протестировал, но должно работать. Если же все `get_X` заменяются отдельно, то надо как-то различать первый `get_Label` и последний.

Comment: Супер! я примерно так и предполагал. Спасибо больше! Сохранили мне пару часов сна :).